# Error creating foreign key (Data Types and Action are Identical)

Tags: mysql, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I am using PHYMyAdmin to create a database and create a relationship. I am getting this error:

```
Error creating foreign key on SectionNumber (check data types)
```

when I try and execute this SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `REGISTER` ADD CONSTRAINT `SectionNumber`
FOREIGN KEY (`SectionNumber`) 
REFERENCES `REGISTRATION_SYSTEM`.`SECTION`(`SectionNumber`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

On this table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `REGISTER` (
  `StudentID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CourseNumber` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SectionNumber` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Semester` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SECTION` (
  `CourseNumber` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SectionNumber` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Semester` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `InstructorStaffID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `MaxEnrollment` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I've searched around a lot and the most common error seem to be a data type mismatch. I am fairly sure my data types for the keys match as you can see from the CREATE TABLE SQL above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the constraint name:

```
ALTER TABLE `REGISTER` ADD CONSTRAINT `SectionNumberConstraint`
FOREIGN KEY (`SectionNumber`) 
REFERENCES `REGISTRATION_SYSTEM`.`SECTION`(`SectionNumber`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: Thanks.
I tried using the changes you suggested, but it did not solve the problem. Still get the same error.